# Regex Filter Arrays And Leave Specific Parts

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently, I am trying to figure out a regex system where the input is `["title of the poll, polloption1 polloption2, polloption3 polloption4"]`.

How can I make it so that RegX filters out anything and returns to me `['polloption1 polloption2', 'polloption3 polloption4']`?

My current code:

```js
const s = ["title of the poll, polloption1 polloption2, polloption3 polloption4"];
console.log(s.split(/(?:^|")([^\s"]+)(?:\s+[^\s"]+)*/).filter(Boolean));
//returns: [ '+poll', ' ', 'option1', '" ', 'option2', '"' ] which is very inacurate
```

Comment: Why do you `.split` an array? Split `s[0]`. Also, please define "anything". Right now, `s[0].split(/\s*,\s*/).slice(1)` will do.

Comment: Why should it remove `title of the poll` and leave `polloption1 polloption2` and `polloption3 polloption4`?

Comment: What is your criteria for filtering?

Comment: Sorry yes, It should remove title of the poll, and leave polloption1 polloption2.

Comment: As for filterting, it would be best if it could be put into an array for easy access to remove.

Comment: Have you tried `"title of the poll, polloption1 polloption2, polloption3 polloption4".split(", ").slice(1)`?

Comment: Not Yet Ill try that rn.

Comment: I was looking for something that would give me a result of `['polloption1 polloption2' ,'polloption3 polloption4']`

Comment: @MihirGarg Doesn't that produce the expected result?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/e2xj840y/: `s[0].split(/\s*,\s*/).slice(1)` yields `[ "polloption1 polloption2", "polloption3 polloption4" ]`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks your solution workes better. Looks like Luis Angel Pena Zuniga answer only worked for the specific words of `[ "polloption1 polloption2", "polloption3 polloption4" ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
s[0].split(/\s*,\s*/).slice(1)
```

It yields `[ "polloption1 polloption2", "polloption3 polloption4" ]`.

The `/\s*,\s*/` regex matches any comma that is enclosed with zero or more whitespaces. The `.slice(1)` removes the first item from the resulting array.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCGGPa/1).

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const s = ["title of the poll, polloption1 polloption2, polloption3 polloption4"];
console.log(s[0].split(/\s*,\s*/).slice(1));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.log(["title of the poll, polloption1 polloption2, polloption3 polloption4"][0].split(/,\s+/).filter(x => /\w+\d\s\w+\d/.test(x)))
```